# How to update mongodb collections

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My collection structure is:

```
col1 = {'class':'12', 'roll':[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Now, I want to `update` the collection `col1` to

```
col1 = {'class':'12', 'roll':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

I added another roll number here, How to update this collection in pymongo.

Answer (score 3):

```
 db.col1.update( { class : 12}, { $push : { roll : 5 } } )
```

Comment: nice. but lust is ")", not "}"

Comment: thanks, fixed (though it is probably still more pseudo-syntax or JS-syntax than Python, but one should get the idea).